# Install module on CD Could not find configuration node: databases/database[@id='master']

Tags: sxa, sitecore-commerce

I am working on scaled installation of `sitecore 9 update 2`.On CD server, I needed to install the `SXA` module, for doing that I was suggested to use CD as CM by adding the "master connection string" in `connectionstring.config` file.

When I use the master connection string in CD and try to install the module in CD environment so it adds the configuration and class libraries, i am getting the following error

```
Could not find configuration node: databases/database[@id='master']
```

Any Ideas?

Note - I am using powershell script to install the sxa module on CD envioenment.

Answer (score 6):

SXA comes with a special package for the CD. If I recall correctly you simply unzip the package and dump out onto the server in the Sitecore web root.

These instructions are documented in the installation guide.

The master database is not used in the content delivery environment and often times that database is nowhere near it.

Furthermore, Sitecore PowerShell Extensions should not be configured on a content delivery server. I highly encourage your project team to consult with an architect familiar with how this should be configured as you could expose your website to malicious activity.

Comment: I am following this https://github.com/CommerceMinion/Sitecore-Commerce-v902-Scaled-Installation and it says that we need to enable CD as CM

Comment: Yes I see that in the guide but it also says CM configuration is temporary. it appears to only be required when running the deploy script listed. I do not see it explicitly say install SPE and SXA. Did I miss read that?

Answer (score 3):

The idea of that link 1 
https://github.com/CommerceMinion/Sitecore-Commerce-v902-Scaled-Installation is to install the sitecore package(dlls and its configurations) on CD server.Copying master section from Sitecore.config should fix the issue for you.You can also modify the role:define value in app settings.config in web.config to the following value so it behaves as CM server.

Update the value to the following key from ContentDelivery

```
 <add key="role:define" value="ContentManagement"/>
```

Again this should be temporary till you run the powershell script.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/CommerceMinion/Sitecore-Commerce-v902-Scaled-Installation also describes that you should copy the "master" database section from the `App_Config/Sitecore.config` on the CM to the `App_Config/Sitecore.config` on the CD. That section is clearly missing on the CD, as you're getting the `Could not find configuration node: databases/database[@id='master']` error message.